# How to SUM DISTINCT by other columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a CTE that resulting something like this:

```
i x y 
A 4 ...
A 4 ... 
A 4 ...
A 4 ...
B 2 ...
B 2 ...
C 3 ...
```

And already have a query that uses most of them:

```
WITH cte AS ( ... ) -- above is the example result of the cte
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN ... THEN i END)) bla_count1
  , COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN ... THEN i END)) bla_count2
  , SUM(x)/COUNT(*) bla_average
  -- and much more similar to above
  , -- how to get sum of A, B, C (4+2+3)
FROM cte
```

How to get the SUM of `x` DISTINCT by `i` (4+2+3)?

[Modified Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1270e761449a88259d1a2d3f3b1c8d03)

Comment: Please, use [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c220425dac85d8cee3f2b2088b5dac0e) fiddle to show us an example of your query. [Edit] your question and add a link to your fiddle.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f40559818d666a42c7b6c388bad76e9a

Comment: Your example CTE output shows that all `x` values for each separate `i` value are identical. Does this is strictly defined by CTE, or this is random, and there may be 2 or more different `x` per `i`?

Comment: @Akina mostly identical but not always (so I decided to use MAX)

Comment: *but not always* Imagine one of 4 rows with `i=A` have `x=5` - what result do you need in this case? 5+2+3? 4+5+2+3?

Comment: @Akina 5 (max)+2+3 or 4 (min)+2+3 or 4.x (average)+2+3 would be fine; sorry for not be clear enough :3

Comment: o_O You don't care what result you get? maybe you do not need in this value at all in this case? anycase it is about nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found a way, by adding one more CTE

```
WITH cte AS ( ... )
, sum1 AS (
  SELECT i, MAX(x) tot -- or AVERAGE/MIN
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT ...
   , (SELECT SUM(tot) FROM sum1) AS sum1
FROM cte
```

Comment: You may obtain this MAX() in current CTE using window form of the aggregate function as additional column in each row, and do not use additional CTE.